# on its way to you usage

Tags: expressions

I trying to express that something has been sent but not yet delivered. Does the following sentence express this correctly for American English?

> Your package has not arrived, is on its way to you.

PD that is in the context of a gift card, for a present that I buy but have not arrived in time, so I giving a gift card instead.

Comment: In answer to your question:  No.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the person to whom you're communicating is a native English speaker, just say,

> Your package is in the mail.

That says it all, believe it or not. Note well, however: The sentence "It's in the mail" can also be used in a deceptive way, as when, for example, a landlord calls you on your cellphone, asking you where his rent check is. If you say, "It's in the mail," beware! That *could* mean you have *not yet sent* the rent check (and may never send it)!

Since your given name is Spanish, I assume you know that the word *mañana* can mean *tomorrow*, but it can also mean *never*.

Mother to son:

> "José, take the garbage out now!"

José to mother:

> "Mañana."

Comment: @José:  De nada, y con mucho gusto! don Don